# cutting string by iterative word in Python

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, cut

For a project in Python 3, I am trying to cut a long .txt file into pieces, which I'd like to store into a list. The aim of the programme is to analyse sentences for various linguistic elements.

Currently, I am stuck at the following: all text samples begin with "Text [0-9]*", followed by the texts themselves. I have read the entire file into memory, and now I want to commit each part into a dictionary. I currently have this:

```
import re

filename = input("Please input filename: ")
if len(filename) < 1: filename = "sample.txt"

try:
    fhandle = open(filename, "r", encoding ='ISO-8859-1')
    print ("file opened:", filename)
except:
    print ("file cannot be opened:", filename)
    quit()

data = ""
length = 0
for line in fhandle:
    if re.match("Text [0-9]", line):
        line = "\n"+line
    else:
        line = line.strip()

text = re.findall("(Text [0-9](\S|\s)*)\nText [0-9]", data)
for items in texts:
    print (items)
```

The problem is that I keep getting a list with a length of 1, instead of 52 items (52 texts). What am I doing wrong with my regular expression/findall technique? Later on, I will need to do the same thing to cut sentences.

Comment: you're not storing the list of lines in `data`.

Comment: try `data=[]`, then `data.append(line)` in your loop, then `data = "\n".join(data)`.